# ".playVideo is not a function" when trying to play youtube video javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to play a youtube video with javascript and the `<iframe>` tag. So far I'm getting this error: "document.getElementById(...).playVideo is not a function". Here's my code:

Javascript:
`document.getElementById("video").playVideo();`

HTML: 
`<iframe id="video" src="url"> </iframe>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to autoplay the video ? In that case you will need to add ?autoplay=1 at the end of the youtube URL and add an allow attribute to your iframe tag like shown below

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?autoplay=1" allow='autoplay'></iframe>
```

If you want to use javascript to control the videoplayer, I would recommend using the Youtube Player API. Sample code is as below (taken from youtube's documentation) -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want further detailed examples, it is very well-documented here -

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference